# How to stop Bash expansion of '*.h" in a function?

Tags: bash

In trying to run the following function—Bash is expanding my variable in an unexpected way—thus preventing me from getting my expected result.

It comes down to the way bash deals with a `"*.h"` which I am passing in to the function.

Here is the function I call:

```
link_files_of_type_from_directory "*.h" ./..
```

And where I would expect this variable to stay this way all the way through at some point, by the time it hits the `echo $command_to_run;` part of my Bash script...this variable has expanded to...

```
MyHeader1.h MyHeader2.h MyHeader3.h
```

and so on.

What I want is for Bash to not expand my files so that my code runs the following:

```
find ./.. -type f -name '*.h'
```

Instead of

```
find ./.. -type f -name  MyHeader1.h MyHeader2.h MyHeader3.h
```

This is the code:

```
function link_files_of_type_from_directory {
    local file_type=$1;
    local directory_to_link=$2;

    echo "File type $file_type";
    echo "Directory to link $directory_to_link";

    command="find $directory_to_link -type f -name $file_type";
    echo $command;

    #for i in $(find $directory_to_link -type f -name $file_type);
    for i in $command;
        do 
            echo $i;
            if test -e $(basename $i); then
            echo $i exists;
            else
            echo Linking: $i;
            ln -s $i;
            fi
    done;
}
```

How can I prevent the expansion so that Bash does search for files that end in `*.h` in my the directory I want to pass in?

UPDATE 1:

So I've updated the call to be

```
link_files_of_type_from_directory "'*.h'" ..
```

And the function now assembles the string of the command to be evaluated like so:

```
mmd="find $directory_to_link -type f -name $file_type";
```

When I echo it out—it's correct :)

```
find .. -type f -name '*.h'
```

But I can't seem to get the `find` command to actually run. Here are the errors / mistakes I'm getting while trying to correctly assemble the `for` loop:

```
# for i in $mmd;        # LOOPS THROUGH STRINGS IN COMMAND
# for i in '$(mdd)';  # RUNS MMD LITERALLY
# for i in ${!mmd};   # Errors out with: INVALID VARIABLE NAME — find .. -type f -name '*.h':
```

Would love help on this part—even though it is a different question :)

Comment: Double-quote your variable references. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) is good at spotting problems like this.

Comment: Thank you! I now have the correct string—but I can't seem to eval it into giving me the results I want :/  # for i in $mmd;        # LOOPS THROUGH STRINGS IN COMMAND
 # for i in '$(mdd)';  # RUNS MMD LITERALLY
 # for i in ${!mmd};   # Errors out with: INVALID VARIABLE NAME — find .. -type f -name '*.h':

Comment: @ovatsug25, comments are terrible with formatting. I suggest you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61492028/edit) and add an "UPDATE" section to the top of bottom with clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With quoting of your variables, removed semicolons and your loop wrapped into an `-exec` action to prevent problems with spaces, tabs and newlines in filenames, your function looks like this:

```
function link_files_of_type_from_directory {
    local file_type=$1
    local directory_to_link=$2

    echo "File type $file_type"
    echo "Directory to link $directory_to_link"

    find "$directory_to_link" -type f -name "$file_type" -exec sh -c '
      for i do
        echo "$i"
        if test -e "$(basename "$i")"; then
          echo "$i exists"
        else
          echo "Linking: $i"
          ln -s "$i"
        fi
      done
    ' sh {} +
}
```